# HTML count bar code error

Tags: javascript, html

Non-working code:

```
<html>
<body>
   <p id="timeCountBar">-></p>
   <script>
      var timeCountBarText = document.getElementById("timeCountBar").innerHTML;
      function subCount(){
          timeCountBarText="-"+timeCountBarText;
          document.getElementById('timeCountBar.innerHTML').innerHTML=timeCountBarText;
      }
      function countTime(){
          for (int i; i < 100; i++){
              setTimeout("subCount",10);
          }
          //something to do after counting has ended
      }
      countTime();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Only showed `->` and nothing else happened.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

HTML:

```
<p id="timeCountBar">-></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var timeCountBarText = document.getElementById("timeCountBar").innerHTML;

var sc = setInterval(function(){subCount()}, 10);

var i=0;

var subCount = function() {
    timeCountBarText = "-" + timeCountBarText;

    document.getElementById('timeCountBar').innerHTML = timeCountBarText;

    i=i+1;

    if(i==100){
    clearInterval(sc);
    }
}
```

You can see it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aniruddha153/Ezres/

You had 3 problems:

1. Logic was not entirely correct.
2. you should not use `setTimeout`. Instead you should use `setInterval`. And the right way to declare setInterval is
   `setInterval(function(){subCount()}, 10);`
3. You need to use `clearInterval`

Reference: [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: @jamie If you understood and got it, please click accept for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two major problems.

---

The first is easily discovered by looking at the JavaScript console in your browser.

JavaScript is not JavaScript, `int` should be `var`.

---

The second is that `setTimeout` is not sleep. You need to call `subCount` either recursively with `setTimeout` or by using `setInterval` instead of using a for loop.