# JS getElementsByClassName(ClassName) Not Working : Nothing Happened

Tags: javascript, html

Code :

(HTML)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Float Image Gallery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="showAllGalleries();">Show gallery</button>
    <div id="myGallery" class="gallery">
      <div class="gallery-close">
        <img src="http://bit.do/closeicon" onclick="showAds" />
      </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>

<style>
.gallery {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  right:auto;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  opacity:50%;
}

.gallery-close {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:4px;
  margin-left:4px;
}
<style>

<script>    
function showMyGallery(){
    document.getElementById('myGallery').style.display='inline';
}

function showAllGalleries(){
  var adsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery");
  for (int i; i<adsArray.length; i++){
    adsArray[i].style.display='inline';
  }
}

function hideMyGallery(){
  document.getElementById('myGallery').style.display='inline';
}
</script>
```

However, showAllGalleries() doesn't seem to work.
What's the problem in my ***Javascript*** code?
Please ***try to avoid*** suggesting answers using jQuery / language other than Javascript.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is there an error in your console? Are you using Internet Explorer 8 or lower? Is your `<script>` element really outside of your `<html>` element?

Comment: What browser and version? getElementsByClassName doesn't exist in IE before version 9

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/ - You're welcome.

Comment: hi, crazy men. the problem in at `int` and should be `var`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<adsArray.length; i++){
    adsArray[i].style.display='inline';
  }
```

You don't have `int`, `string`, `float` and other data types as you have in other languages. In javascript all you have is `var`

Comment: Very smart. THis is the second time I make mistake & ask question in SO. Check out my answer & ___laugh at me___:):)

Comment: And then missed that `=0` and maybe it became undefined value ::)

Comment: No, 15 minutes or something like this. Not about your styling problem (hey, i saw you doing sth. like this!)!

Comment: @Jamie, no not that. You said that this was your second time making a mistake. What was the first?

Comment: The first time is here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404965/html-count-bar-code-error).